# Floating Youtube iframe embed

Tags: jquery, iframe, youtube

I've seen jQuery scripts calculate the hight of 100%/resizable width youtube embeds of the old style (object/embed).

Anyone know how to solve it with the new iframe embeds?

```
<iframe 
  title="YouTube video player" 
  class="youtube-player" 
  type="text/html" 
  width="640"
  height="390" 
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/-p3atsZRPLc?rel=0" 
  frameborder="0" 
  allowFullScreen 
></iframe>
```

Comment: `width()` does not work on the iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using the old style embed and this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        //<![CDATA[
          var $origVideo = $(".youtube, .youtube embed");
          var aspectRatio = $origVideo.attr("height") / $origVideo.attr("width");

          $(window).resize(function() {
            var wrapWidth = $("#video").width();
            $origVideo
                .width(wrapWidth)
                .height(wrapWidth * aspectRatio);
          }).trigger("resize");
        //]]>
</script>
```